# How to solve $y''-3y^2 =0$ with a system of ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve $y''-3y^2 =0$, i use the substitution $w=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Using the chain rule i have:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{dw}{dx} = \frac{dw}{dy}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = w \cdot \frac{dw}{dy}$$
So i can build the system:
$$w\cdot \frac{dw}{dy} = 3y^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = w$$

But i'm not sure how to solve the system. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is there a reason _why_ you want to do it this way, as opposed to simply multiplying by $y'$ and integrating?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate many times over...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you did is right, you could integrate as separable variables:

$\int wdw = \int 3y^2dy$ , so $\frac{w^2}2 = y^3 +C_1 => w=\pm\sqrt{2y^3+2C_1}$

then

$\int \frac1{w(y)}dy = \int dx$

$\int \frac1{\pm\sqrt{2y^3+2C_1}}dy = x$

Comment: Assuming the first integration constant is zero, we get $y(x)=\frac{2}{(x+C_2)^2}$. Wondering if it is possible to do without this assumption.

Comment: you are right, I removed the matrix part

Answer (score -1):

$$
y''-3y^2=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y'y''-3y^2y'=0
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{1}{2}(y')^2-y^3=c
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y'=\pm\sqrt{2y^3+c'}.
$$